# $f : \mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ is not onto.

Tags: general-topology

> **Question :** $f : \mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ is a continuous map s.t. for *almost all* $x\in \mathbb{S}^1$ in Lebesgue measure, there is an open ball $B(x,\delta)$ s.t. $f|B(x,\delta)$ is a rectifiable path. Then $f$ is not a onto map. How can we prove this ?

Remark : (1) There is a continuous map $f: [0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]^2$ s.t. a closure of $f([0,1])$ is $[0,1]^2$.

(2) $\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ has a measure $0$ by Sard theorem.

Reference : Exercise 6 in 45p. in Differential topology - Guillemin and Pollack

Comment: you'll want to add assumptions on $f$

Comment: Assuming $f$ is smooth, since $S^1$ has dimension 1 and $S^2$ has dimension 2, every point in the image of $f$ is a critical point. Apply Sard and you're done.

Comment: By *almost* do you mean **almost all** (in the sense of Lebesgue measure)?  Then it's not true.

Comment: @D. Brogan : Thank you (Smooth case which is desired by me).

Comment: @Robert Israel : How do we construct a counterexample ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: 
The [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) maps $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$ and is constant on each connected component of the complement of the Cantor set $E$.  Then using a space-filling curve you can map $[0,1]$ continuously onto $\mathbb S^2$.
Almost every point of $[0,1]$ is in $E^c$ and thus has a neighbourhood on which this function is constant.  If you don't like your "rectifiable path" to be a single point, you can replace it by a small loop in each component of $E^c$.